# How to add canvas programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a noob question =P
How can I programatically add a canvas to a grid? When I use

```
 Canvas _canvas = new Canvas( )
        {
            Name = "newCanvas",
            Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible,
            Margin = new Thickness( 100, 0, 0, 100 ),
            Width = 100000,
            Height = 100000,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush { Color = new Color { R = 255, G = 255, B = 255, A = 1 } }
        };
```

and then say `LayoutRoot.Children.Add( _canvas );`

nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: The width and height are huge. Is that intentionally?

Comment: Yes, they are intetionally so big, so that I wouldn't miss out on something silly, like it being just out of view or whatever. 
But as Ku6opr stated, it was the alpha, being set to 1, in stead of 255 =3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Alpha` parameter is also 0 - 255, not 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: =P hehe damn! That was indeed the problem ! I was staring at it for hours on end!